# Adding custom editorarea CSS using a FCKeditor plugin

Tags: javascript, css, fckeditor

I wrote a [plugin](https://github.com/mattalexx/dynamicelement-fckeditor) for FCKeditor that inserts `<div>` tags into HTML for later replacement with dynamic data.

I use the [fake image approach](https://github.com/mattalexx/dynamicelement-fckeditor/blob/master/dialog/fck_insert.js#L85) to insert an image placeholder into the visual part of the FCKeditor window. That image is connected to the `<div>` as it appears in the source. This approach is also used by the native page break functionality native to FCKeditor.

I want to apply some styles to that image. Specifically, I want to add a icon image to the background. I have been adding the CSS to my custom editorarea CSS file that I specified in my config file. But I'd like to move that code into the plugin directory somehow.

Is there a way to add custom CSS to the editoarea using Javascript in a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written exactly this kind of plug-in myself in the past. Looking at my code, it seems I concluded that it wasn't possible (or at least straightforward) to add custom CSS to the edit document, so I specify everything on the `style` object of the image placeholder in the plugin script, including a background image that lives in the plugin directory.